# Сортировка коллекции, где нужно переопределить размеры в нужном порядке

Tags: javascript

С backend-a приходят данные с размерами. Часть данных подвергались изменению через 1С, что привело к тому, что размеры перепутаны. Как мне отсортировать размеры в правильном порядке?

Так данные приходят в данный момент:

```js
let sizes = [
  {size: "S"},
  {size: "M"},
  {size: "L"},
  {size: "XS"},
];
```

Размер XS должен быть перед размером S. Бывают ситуации, когда размер, который должен быть вначале коллекции, находится где то в середине или же ситуации, когда размер который должен быть вначале коллекции определён в конце неё. По этой причине решение с поиском последнего элемента массива и переопределение его через тот же slice не решит проблему. 
Сама размерная сетка выглядит примерно так: ['xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', '2xl', '3xl']
Можно ли как то "научить" сортирующую функцию, перебирать и переопределять размеры в нужном порядке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это использовав свой компаратор:

```js
let order = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL', '3XL'];

let sizes = ["S", "XL", "L", "XS", "L", "3XL", "XS", "2XL"];
sizes.sort(function(a, b) {
  return order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b);
});
console.log(sizes);
```

О компараторах в `JS` можете прочитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно)