# Как отсортировать массив по строковым значениям другого массива?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть два массива объектов:

Первый массив:

```
[
    {id: "as3cdf114gte", name: "qwer", property: "1234"},
    {id: "e56cdf1fggte", name: "rqewrq", property: "4322"},
    {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", name: "qwerwq", property: "12342"}
]
```

Второй массив:

```
[
    {id: "e56cdf1fggte", data : 1},
    {id: "as3cdf114gte", data : 2},
    {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", data : 4}
]
```

Как отсортировать второй массив по значению полей `id` первого массива?

В итоге должно получиться:

```
[
    {id: "as3cdf114gte", data : 2},
    {id: "e56cdf1fggte", data : 1},
    {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", data : 4}
]
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сложить два массива php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001679/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-php)

Comment: Несмотря на то, что вопрос-дубликат имеет несколько другой смысл и заголовок, но решение то же. Вам тут не надо сортировать ничего, это более затратно. Из второго массива делаете ключ-значение, а потом проходите по первому и добавляете в него `data` по ключу.

Comment: @teran не понимаю, в чем он является дубликатом, мне не надо ничего изменять в первом массиве, в нем есть свои данные, которые я в виде примера не стал показывать. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы элементы второго массива шли в томже порядке, что и в первом

Comment: оу. че то я на метки попутал. тут js. убрал закрытие, пардоньте. На самом деле это ничего не меняет, из певого массива вырезать id не сложно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const first = [
  {id: "as3cdf114gte", name: "qwer", property: "1234"},
  {id: "e56cdf1fggte", name: "rqewrq", property: "4322"},
  {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", name: "qwerwq", property: "12342"}
];

const second = [
  {id: "e56cdf1fggte", data : 1},
  {id: "as3cdf114gte", data : 2},
  {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", data : 4}
];

// Формируем вспомогательный массив из `id` первого массива.
const order = first.map(item => item.id);

// Сортируем второй массив согласно индексам вспомогательного.
second.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.id) - order.indexOf(b.id));

console.log({
  first,
  second
})
```

---

Использованы материалы ответа на вопрос: [Сортировка коллекции, где нужно переопределить размеры в нужном порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/971987/256824)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [
    {id: "as3cdf114gte", name: "qwer", property: "1234"},
    {id: "e56cdf1fggte", name: "rqewrq", property: "4322"},
    {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", name: "qwerwq", property: "12342"}
];

var b = [
    {id: "e56cdf1fggte", data : 1},
    {id: "as3cdf114gte", data : 2},
    {id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", data : 4}
];

var c = []; //resulting array

var tindex = 0;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    c[i] = {};
    tindex = b.findIndex(x => x.id === a[i].id);
    c[i].id = b[tindex].id;
    c[i].data = b[tindex].data;
}

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Как уже писал в комментах к вопросу, сортировать смысла нет. надо взять "колонку" `id` из первого массива в нужном порядке, и составив словарик из второго сформировать результат. Если вы, конечно, опять что-нибудь не упустили в вопросе.

```js
var a = [{id: "as3cdf114gte", name: "qwer", property: "1234"},{id: "e56cdf1fggte", name: "rqewrq", property: "4322"},{id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", name: "qwerwq", property: "12342"}];
var b = [{id: "e56cdf1fggte", data : 1},{id: "as3cdf114gte", data : 2},{id: "as3trfgfi4ggf6", data : 4}];

var data = b.reduce( (acc, v) => ( acc[v.id] = v.data, acc) , {});
var result = a.map( v => ({ id: v.id, data: data[v.id] }) );

console.log(result);
```